# How to find a start and stop od a break in GPS tracker data?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, gps-time

I have a data from GPS tracker.
Let's say something like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gps_data` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `speed` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `time` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and some sample data:

```
INSERT INTO `gps_data` (`id`, `speed`, `time`) VALUES
  ('1', '5', '07:00'),
  ('2', '10', '07:10'),
  ('3', '0', '07:20'),
  ('4', '0', '07:30'),
  ('5', '0', '07:40'),
  ('6', '0', '07:50'),
  ('7', '20', '08:00'),
  ('8', '40', '08:10'),
  ('9', '15', '08:15'),
  ('10', '0', '08:32'),
  ('11', '0', '08:40'),
  ('12', '0', '08:52'),
  ('13', '12', '09:10'),
  ('14', '0', '09:25');
```

**The question is how to find a time of first and last position with speed = 0.**

So in my example I would like to have something like:

```
[break_start, break_stop]
[07:20, 07:50]
[08:32, 08:52]
[09:25, NULL]
```

Here is the Fiddle to better understanding: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d79228/4

What I have started to try is:

```
SELECT `time` AS break_start, `time` AS break_stop  FROM `gps_data` WHERE `speed`=0;
```

Comment: What if the data spans across multiple days ? How will it be resolved just using time values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method in MySQL is to assign a group to each row.  This group can be the number of non-zero values before the row -- all rows with adjacent zero values are in the same group.

In MySQL 8+, you can use window functions for this:

```
select min(time), max(time)
from (select t.*,
             sum(speed <> 0) over (order by time) as grp
      from t
     ) t
where speed = 0
group by grp;
```

In earlier versions, one method is a correlated subquery:

```
select min(time), max(time)
from (select t.*,
             (select count(*)
              from t t2
              where t2.speed <> 0 and t2.time <= t.time
             ) as grp
      from t
     ) t
where speed = 0
group by grp;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d79228/11) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Thank you. Work as expected

Comment: Gordon Linoff: thank you once again for help. I've tested this query in my production DB however works slower then expected. About 18s for this query. Is there something which could be improved in terms of speed?

Comment: @Tikky . . . Can you ask another question regarding performance?